# Does StringBuilder.toString retain the built string?

Tags: java, android, stringbuilder

I'm creating a StringBuilder to collect strings that I periodically flush to a server.  If the flush fails, I want to keep the strings to try again next time, although in the mean time I might get additional strings to send which must be added to the StringBuilder.

What I want to know is what the most efficient way to do this would be, as this is being done in an Android app where battery usage and thus CPU usage is a big concern.  Does calling StringBuilder's toString() function store the resulting string it returns internally so that a subsequent call doesn't have to do the work of copying all the original strings over?  Or if the call fails, should I create a new StringBuilder initialized with the return value from toString()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the [OpenJDK source code for `StringBuilder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java):

```
public String toString() {
    // Create a copy, don't share the array
    return new String(value, 0, count);
}
```

The [source for the `String` constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String) with those parameters is:

```
public String(char value[], int offset, int count) {
    if (offset < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset);
    }
    if (count < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(count);
    }
    // Note: offset or count might be near -1>>>1.
    if (offset > value.length - count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset + count);
    }
    this.offset = 0;
    this.count = count;
    this.value = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, offset, offset+count);
}
```

So yes, it does create a new `String` everytime, and yes, it makes a copy of the `char[]` everytime.

**It's important to note that this is one implementation of `toString`, and another implementation may obviously be different.**

Answer (score 0):

It would be an implementation detail.  Since java strings are immutable a correct impl can choose to share or create new strings from StringBuilder.toString() even if it's not needed.

As everyone says, you can test to see if this is indeed a real performance issue for you.  If it is one (clunky) workaround is to wrap StringBuilder and cache the resulting string.  You can use a dirty flag to indicate the content was modified.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder.toString API says that *a **new** String object is allocated and initialized to contain the character sequence currently represented by this object.*